# Working with logical functors in Prolog

Tags: prolog, logic, semantics, ontology

I want to have logical connectives such as

`not(X), conj(X, Y), some(Y, K).` and I want to be able to iterate over them.

So for example I want to be able to convert not(some(Y, K)), into all(Y, not(K)).

I don't want them to have any particular meaning, I just want to work with the logical formulas in this way.

What's the best way to do this?

Here's an actual line in my code:

```
nnf(not(all(X, Y)) ,some(Z, W))     :- nnf(X, Z), nnf(not(Y), W).
```

So if I give it `not(all(a,b))` I want to get back some(a, not(b)), but atm I don't know how to get Prolog to treat `not/1` and `all/2` in such a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a unique best way here. It depends a bit on your particular uses.

Your question essentially reduces to: How should variables be represented in your setting. By a ground term? That is a (Prolog) variable free representation. Or directly by Prolog variables.

I'd rather try a ground representation first. Maybe try `v(Nr)` with Nr an integer. A relatively frequent one is `'$VAR'(Nr)` which is also recognized by `writeq/1`. But I would stick with `v/1` in the beginning.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply. But I don't really understand what you mean. I need to be able to do something like this, give something like not(some(a, b)) to a function and get back all(a, not(b)).

Comment: your_function(not(some(X, Y)), all(X, not(Y))). is enough for this particular case. What would you like to generalize ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Thea project](https://github.com/vangelisv/thea). It develops a Prolog library for manipulating OWL2 ontologies. Maybe they have already implemented the negation normal form conversion.